# PHP undefined index on array lookup

Tags: php, arrays

I have a list of IP's in a text file.  I want get the user's IP and then count in the array to see if they have made more than 2 requests.

However I am getting

```
Undefined index: xx.xxx.xxx.xx
```

where

```
xx.xxx.xxx.xx is my IP.
```

(hiding for obvious reasons)

When I have more than 2 of the same IP in the txt file it returns the 'Too many lookups'  but if the $value isn't found in the array it returns undefined index.  I thought I had the catch with !isset but if I remove the ! it just runs the request.  If I keep it as !isset it runs but then returns undefined index.

I have even tried

```
if(array_key_exists($value, $array_list)){
```

but nothing.  Any ideas why?

```
$list = file_get_contents('ips.txt');

// convert to array
$array_list = (explode(" ",$list));

// Get user's ip
$value = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if(!isset($array_list[$value])){

    $values = array_count_values($array_list); 
    $count = $values[$value];

    if ($count > 2) {
        return 'Too many lookup attempts, please try again in 24    hours click <a href="/">HERE</a> to return home';
        }

    }

    else {
        // run the ok request
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you're confusing array **values** and array **keys**

Explode returns an array where all the items from the string are **values** and the keys are just numbers starting from 0. Take this example:

```
$string = "foo bar baz";
$array = explode(' ', $string);
/*
 * Array now holds
 * [0] => "foo",
 * [1] => "bar",
 * [2] => "baz",
 */
```

In the example 0,1,2 are the **keys** and foo, bar, baz are the **values**.

So when you execute

```
// convert to array
$array_list = (explode(" ",$list));
```

Your keys are the numbers 0-n (n being however many IPs were in the list). Each key has a corresponding value, those values are the actual IPs.

So now when you run

```
if(!isset($array_list[$value])){
```

What you're telling PHP to do is to find an entry in the array with **key** that matches your IP. Except no keys in the array are IP addresses.

If you want to find out if a certain value exists in the array use [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php).  OR in your case, since you're running your list through `array_count_values()` which is going to convert your **values** into **keys**, you could do a normal `isset()` lookup on the *$values* variable after running the function.

```
$values = array_count_values($array_list); // Each IP is now a key of $values
if (isset($values[$value])) {
    // The IP shows up at least once
    $count = $values[$value];

    // continue with other logic here
}
else {
    // The IP is not in the list

    // continue with other logic here
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the detailed reply.  This makes a lot more sense than what I thought i was trying to do.